UTF-8 encoding not rendering latin symbols on IOS systems
I have an static html page encoded in utf-8 and I'm using ios supported fonts as roboto and Segoe UI. Now my page is failling to render accets and special spanish characters. This happens only on ios based systems and it does not accur on windows.
I'm adding utf-8 to each header through JS:
// Meta tags
const charsetMeta = document.createElement('meta');
charsetMeta.setAttribute('charset', 'UTF-8');
head.appendChild(charsetMeta);

I have tried using iso-8859-15 encodig but the problem persisted.


How did you open that page? Is it served by some web server?

Opened locally on a friends mac

Try to add  into page ... block directly, not by js. And make sure your accent characters are actually written in utf-8

See my answer. •

Your UTF8 file was encoded as ISO 8859-1. The UTF-8 characters take multiple bytes, whereas ISO 8859-1 is a single-byte encoding.

I triedUTF-8 and still doesn't work.
This mostly happens in letters with accents like: á
Could it be that I have been copy/pasting this letters from a document that I have? since I don't have a spanish keyboard to make those special characters.
